# SVNKit: Commit files that were manually deleted from filesystem( Work Copy)

Tags: java, svnkit

I can not solve the problem with collecting CommitItem(changes that commit), or more accurately, I have no porblem with the changed and added files BUT files that I manually deleted from the file system is not seen in CommitItem list ... And those changes can not commit to the SVN server.

If I delete a file using the API, then the problem does not exist... but manually deleting ...

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

If a file has been manually removed from the file system, can't do a commit, cause SVN thinks that it should be there but it isn't. Just try svn status on such a situation (!)...

Comment: Ok,but if you use TortoiseSVN client the file is displayed in the dialog box (marked as a missing file) and commit to SVNServer.... in this case it is not so...

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone had a similar problem?

Yes, yo have that case because svn has info about that file in .svn dir.

1. run `svn update`
2. deleted all files as `svn delete` command

FYI: when you delete file using `svn deleted` it is deleted and info of local svn storage is updated, if you deleted the folder this way don't be surprised that folder still exists, it is because use folder as root for its storage and it will be deleted after commit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zaletniy,

this is smart .... :)

If it is a big difference between Work Copy and Repository this operation is expensive ... but if that is the singular solution ....

Although, I thought that the SVNKit acts as Tortoise. Tortoise can detect files that were manually deleted